# Launching app in background in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there a way that I can use the url scheme approach to launch an application in the background or if it is already running in the background invoke it without it (the callee) coming to the foreground? I heard that this can be done in iOS 4.2 but don't see it when I use

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

to open the application.
Thanks,
N.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like it is possible.

> If your application is not running when a URL request arrives, it is launched and moved to 
>   the foreground so that it can open the
>   URL. The implementation of your
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   method should retrieve the URL from
>   its options dictionary and determine
>   whether the application can open it.
>   If it can, return YES and let your
>   application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
>   or application:handleOpenURL: method
>   handle the actual opening of the URL.
>
> If your application is running but is
>   in the background or suspended, it is
>   moved to the foreground to open the
>   URL. Shortly thereafter, the system
>   calls the delegate’s
>   application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
>   to check the URL and open it. If your
>   delegate does not implement this
>   method (or the current system version
>   is iOS 4.1 or earlier), the system
>   calls your delegate’s
>   application:handleOpenURL: method
>   instead.

[iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html)